# Error while running the jmeter Perfmon plugin

Tags: jmeter

```
2022-01-10 09:02:52,633 INFO o.j.r.PluginManager: Plugins Status: [jpgc-perfmon=2.1, jpgc-plugins-manager=0.20, jmeter-core=5.4.3, jmeter-ftp=5.4.3, jmeter-http=5.4.3, jmeter-jdbc=5.4.3, jmeter-jms=5.4.3, jmeter-junit=5.4.3, jmeter-java=5.4.3, jmeter-ldap=5.4.3, jmeter-mail=5.4.3, jmeter-mongodb=5.4.3, jmeter-native=5.4.3, jmeter-tcp=5.4.3, jmeter-components=5.4.3]
2022-01-10 09:02:52,633 INFO o.j.r.PluginManagerMenuItem: Plugins Manager has upgrades: [jpgc-plugins-manager]
2022-01-10 09:07:25,300 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2022-01-10 09:07:25,316 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2022-01-10 09:07:25,316 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2022-01-10 09:07:25,316 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2022-01-10 09:07:25,331 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2022-01-10 09:07:25,331 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2022-01-10 09:07:39,139 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2022-01-10 09:07:39,139 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2022-01-10 09:07:39,139 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2022-01-10 09:07:39,139 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2022-01-10 09:07:39,558 INFO o.a.j.v.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Add JavaFX to your Java installation if you want to use renderer: org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderInBrowser
2022-01-10 09:10:59,197 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='D:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin'
2022-01-10 09:10:59,197 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='D:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\examples\CSVjmeter'
2022-01-10 09:10:59,665 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2022-01-10 09:10:59,681 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2022-01-10 09:10:59,681 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2022-01-10 09:10:59,790 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2022-01-10 09:10:59,790 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2022-01-10 09:10:59,790 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2022-01-10 09:10:59,790 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2022-01-10 09:10:59,790 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2022-01-10 09:10:59,915 INFO k.a.j.p.PerfMonCollector: PerfMon metrics will be stored in C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\perfmon_4983807154892038936.jtl
2022-01-10 09:10:59,947 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2022-01-10 09:11:00,116 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2022-01-10 09:11:00,116 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 10 threads for group Thread Group.
2022-01-10 09:11:00,116 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2022-01-10 09:11:00,116 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=10 ramp-up=5 delayedStart=false
2022-01-10 09:11:00,122 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2022-01-10 09:11:00,122 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2022-01-10 09:11:00,122 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2022-01-10 09:11:00,201 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = DESKTOP-LC8U5QA
2022-01-10 09:11:00,216 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0
2022-01-10 09:11:00,388 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.h.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll Socket Factory
2022-01-10 09:11:00,388 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS
2022-01-10 09:11:00,388 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread
2022-01-10 09:11:00,638 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2
2022-01-10 09:11:00,700 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location:  type JKS
2022-01-10 09:11:00,700 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2022-01-10 09:11:00,700 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore
2022-01-10 09:11:01,127 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-3
2022-01-10 09:11:01,617 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-4
2022-01-10 09:11:02,116 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-5
2022-01-10 09:11:02,617 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-6
2022-01-10 09:11:03,117 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-7
2022-01-10 09:11:03,616 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-8
2022-01-10 09:11:04,117 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-9
2022-01-10 09:11:04,617 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-10
2022-01-10 09:12:00,140 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: Thread Group 1-4
2022-01-10 09:12:00,140 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-4
2022-01-10 09:12:00,327 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: Thread Group 1-1
2022-01-10 09:12:00,327 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2022-01-10 09:12:00,359 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: Thread Group 1-9
2022-01-10 09:12:00,359 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-9
2022-01-10 09:12:00,359 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: Thread Group 1-3
2022-01-10 09:12:00,359 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-3
2022-01-10 09:12:00,374 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: Thread Group 1-8
2022-01-10 09:12:00,374 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-8
2022-01-10 09:12:00,390 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: Thread Group 1-2
2022-01-10 09:12:00,390 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-2
2022-01-10 09:12:00,390 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: Thread Group 1-10
2022-01-10 09:12:00,390 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-10
2022-01-10 09:12:00,390 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: Thread Group 1-5
2022-01-10 09:12:00,390 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-5
2022-01-10 09:12:00,405 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: Thread Group 1-6
2022-01-10 09:12:00,405 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-6
2022-01-10 09:12:00,405 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: Thread Group 1-7
2022-01-10 09:12:00,405 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-7
2022-01-10 09:12:00,405 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2022-01-10 09:12:00,405 ERROR k.a.p.c.AbstractTransport: Error during exit
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1035) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at kg.apc.perfmon.client.StreamTransport.writeln(StreamTransport.java:50) ~[perfmon-2.2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.perfmon.client.AbstractTransport.disconnect(AbstractTransport.java:63) [perfmon-2.2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.NewAgentConnector.disconnect(NewAgentConnector.java:36) [jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.shutdownConnectors(PerfMonCollector.java:281) [jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.testEnded(PerfMonCollector.java:149) [jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.testEnded(ResultCollector.java:345) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:218) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:493) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
2022-01-10 09:12:00,515 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Comment: Please next time format errors and code, it's more readable then. Also, it'd be helpful to know a bit more context, a few sentences about what you are doing usually helps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue using the same software versions and test configuration:

[image]

So my expectation is that something is wrong with the network communication between Perfmon Metrics Collector listener and the ServerAgent, I would recommend starting with checking logs on both ends

1. On ServerAgent side [start it with `--loglevel DEBUG` parameter`](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent#usage)
2. On JMeter side you can [increase PerfMon Metrics Collector logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file

   ```
   <Logger name="kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon" level="debug" />
   ```
3. Check whether your `C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\perfmon_4983807154892038936.jtl` file contains any entries, it might be the case you can just ignore this error .